# JSON Deserialize fails when linker is set to Link All

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, xamarin

I am getting an ArgumentNullException when trying to deserialize JSON on device.  Here is the exact error:

[image: deserialize error]

And here is the calling code:

```
private TMetadata ReadObject(string path)
{
    var data = File.ReadAllText(path);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, _settings);
    return (TMetadata) obj;
}
```

I read through [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15152/deserialization-not-working-with-json-net-on-ios-device-ios-simulator-works) and realized it was a linker problem. My project is set to Link All when building to device, and changing it to Don't Link is not feasible due to size constraints.

I inspected the json text and found the type that it was trying to deserialize, then went to that class and marked it as Preserve(AllMembers = true)]. I added the same attribute to any user defined class that was being used in the class. I still get the same error, however.  I also added the --linkskip=AssemblyName to the additional mtouch arguments and had no luck.

Does anyone have any tips? Is there at least any way I can get some more useful information from xamarin? When the exception happens it takes me to a seemingly random line - an event declaration in an unrelated class - and clicking on methods in the stack does nothing. I have no idea what the "method" parameter is.

Here's stack starting just after the ReadObject call:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(object value, string parameterName) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ExpressionReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateParametrizedConstructor(System.Reflection.MethodBase method) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateWrapper(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Bluebeam.Studio.Client.SDK.Sessions.SessionMarkupId,Bluebeam.Studio.Client.SDK.Sessions.ServerState.Pending.PendingItems.PendingMarkupDto> list) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewList(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, bool createdFromNonDefaultCreator) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, System.MonoType objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, object existingValue, string id) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, System.MonoType objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter propertyConverter, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, Bluebeam.Studio.Client.SDK.Sessions.ServerState.Pending.PendingItems.PendingMarkupsData target) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Bluebeam.Studio.Client.SDK.Sessions.ServerState.Pending.PendingItems.PendingMarkupsData newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, string id) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, System.Type objectType, bool checkAdditionalContent) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, System.Type objectType) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader, System.Type objectType) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) in 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) in
```

Comment: "Link all" always gives a lot of headaches, because that the default behavior for Release packages is not "Link all" but "Link SDK assemblies only", that should be enough to reduce the package size. Does it throw the exception if you set it to "Link SDK assemblies only"?

Comment: It works properly when I set it to "Link SDK assemblies only", but it adds an extra 40mb to the app size and we really don't want to do that since we're trying to get it under 100mb so it can be downloaded via cellular.

Comment: I've had similar issues, but setting the linkskip argument worked for me. Is this on Android or iOS? The linker is configured differently for each.

Comment: the apk is 40Mb more with link sdk only? wow, that's a lot,  you may be using a lot of external libraries... I think the problem is not in your class, but on the Json library, when linked it seems to lose some function, try to add to the linker options "--linkskip=NameOfAssemblyToSkipWithoutFileExtension", try first with the json library, if it doesn't works try with other libraries that you may be using.

Comment: @DylanS its an iOS app.

Comment: @Gusman Yeah we use a common code base for the same product across multiple platforms so there are a lot of libraries.  Seems weird to do "--linkskip=Newtonsoft.Json" but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @CaseyHancock if you have multiple dll's of your own (do you use shared projects or dll's for the common base?) is worth a try to check with each one of these, if you find which dll is the one you need to not to link it may give you a hint on what class is the conflictive one.

Comment: @Gusman All the projects that contain the objects that are serialized/deserialized by json are already set to linkskip.

Comment: What is in your settings `_settings`?

Comment: @AkashAmin http://i.imgur.com/M8GiICd.png

Comment: @Gusman "--linkskip=Newtonsoft.Json" fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was adding "--linkskip=Newtonsoft.Json" to the additional mtouch arguments.  Thanks [Gusman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162699/gusman) for the suggestion!